# how to get a data-attribute where has class active

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have a multiple anchor tag like below

```
<a class="sort-type active " data-type="desc" data-field="relevance" href="#" title="" target="_self">relevance</a>
<a class="sort-type " data-type="desc" data-field="most-viewed" href="#" title="" target="_self">most viewer</a>
<a class="sort-type " data-type="desc" data-field="high-price" href="#" title="" target="_self">high-price</a>
```

my question is how can i get the data-field where has class active in it

Comment: `$(".active").data("field")`  https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/ https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure JS solution will be:

```
// document.querySelector(".sort-type.active") - Gets the element with active class
// getAttribute('data-field') - Gets the attribute required from the html

document.querySelector(".sort-type.active").getAttribute('data-field')
```

Comment: It's better to use `dataset` property.

Comment: $(".sort-type.active").data('field')  is with ```dataset``` property. thanks by the way.